# Datetime в часы

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Есть датафрейм с двумя столбцами с форматом %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S. Если вычитаю один столбец из другого, то получаю объект типа timedelta

Мне нужно получить разницу в датах из двух столбцов в часах, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Используйте .astype https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-time-difference-between-two-pandas-columns-in-hours-and-minutes#:~:text=Pandas%20timestamp%20differences

Comment: возьмите `timedelta.total_seconds()` и разделите на количество секунд в часе получите разницу в часах

Comment: @SergFSM я тоже сперва написал такой комментарий, но, кажется, в pandas это стоит делать как-то иначе

Comment: @andreymal, верно, можно иначе (ссылка выше), но и total_seconds в pandas тоже работает